# IPSec VS ssl/tls?

Tags: vpn, ssl, ipsec

I'm currently working on a VPN solution who use IPSec connections, but I'm asking myself about the different VPN possibilities.

First point, according to me IPsec is more secure and Open on the sheet.
Second point, IPsec is working on a lower layer than Ssl/TLS.

So, who's the better? I'm mean in term of security.
I'm working over linux.

Cheers all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on what you mean by security, and on your environment.  Define that and we can get a better idea what answers will work.

Do you need NAT traversal?  Do you need service privacy?  Do you have a defined set of services you need to run, or could it be anything?  What is the network topology?  Do you have 'road warriors'?  Do the road warriors have to be able to get in from busted hotel networks with two layers of NAT (yes, this can happen)?

Answer (score 0):

That depends how Ipsec/IKE is used (PFS actived, Replay attack detection ,no aggressive mode, no psk). If all that is ok, i would go with an IPSec tunnel.

Comment: Well in fact, I would like to secured as possible my VPN acces, for exemple all certificates are store into a Crypto USB Key (I know the key can still be stolen) I have a User and computer (Mac address) filtering. etc.